# Из-за чего русские символы в MySQL заменяются на знаки вопроса?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. Впервые вывела сайт в сеть, и столкнулась с проблемой что текст на русском языке, занесенный в базу, выводится вопросиками в черных ромбах. Не знаю как исправить.
На локальном сервере всё работало на ура.
Пыталась дополнять строчки после присоединения к базе - выдает ошибку.
В phpmyadmin сказано что кодировка utf-8

1. Кодировка utf-8 без BOM в конечном php-файле
2. Заголовок прописан

   header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

   3. БД целиком и каждое поле отдельно в кодировке
      [image: вот]
      utf-8
   4. Мета-тег указан

   5. Черные вопросы как были так и остались
      =((

[image: вот те самые вопросы]

Comment: Используй юникод.

Comment: Так там же хоть юникод хоть генерал и так и так отображается в базе utf8mb4 а просто utf-8 не поставить.

Comment: Или. как использовать этот юникод?

Comment: @Anna при подключении к базе данных _(или при выборе бд после подключения)_ необходимо указать кодировку UTF-8.

Comment: @Anna, в базе `nvarchar`, а не `varchar`; при передаче клиенту utf-8. Про сам php не скажу.

Comment: А может, @Эдуард более прав, чем я...

Comment: $connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);         
 
mysql_select_db("имя базы");

Comment: если после этого добавляю строку про кодировку php ругается и вообще ничего не работает

Comment: @Anna mysql_connect в XXI веке... http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php  почитайте то что в розовом блоке написано.

Comment: проверьте, что 1. все ваши файлы имеют кодировку utf-8, 2. в php прописан загловок header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");  3. База данных, таблички и поля табличек в кодировке utf-8. 4. На странице указан мета тег <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: 1. кодировка utf-8 на всех файлах
2. заголовок прописан
3. БД целиком и каждое поле отдельно в кодировке utf-8
4. мета-тег указан
5. черные вопросы как были так и остались

Comment: Поняла что utf8_general_ci и utf-8 это не одно и тоже, спасибо